# SQL table with all possible employee seating arrangements across 3 floors

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table that shows all possible floor assignment scenarios for my employees. There are a fixed number of seats available on each floor, but exact seating arrangement on each floor does not matter.

I have 30 Employees, each with a unique Employee_ID between 1-30.
I have 3 floors, each with a fixed number of seats available - Floor1 has 5, Floor2 has 15, Floor3 has 10.

I have tried a few different cross joins between the Employee table (Employee_ID) and the Arrangement table (Floor_Number, Seat_Number), but I'm having trouble organizing the results into the possible scenarios.

Any help on how to structure this query would be much appreciated.

Edit: Data described in better detail below

Table - Employees

```
    Employee_ID
    1
    2
    ...
    30
```

Table - Arrangement

```
    Floor_Number | Seat_Number
         1       |     1
         1       |     2
         1       |     3
         1       |     4
         1       |     5
         2       |     1
         2       |     2
         ...     |    ...
         2       |     15
         3       |     1
         3       |     2
         ...     |     ...
         3       |     10
```

Desired Output would be structured like the table below, with all possible seating arrangements across the 3 floors. I assume there will be more than 25 scenarios - this is just here as an example.

```
    Scenario |  Floor_Number | Seat_Number | Employee_ID
        1    |        1      |      1      |      1
        1    |        1      |      2      |      2
        1    |        1      |      3      |      3
        1    |        1      |      4      |      4
        1    |        1      |      5      |      5
        1    |        2      |      1      |      6
        .............................................
        25   |        1      |      1      |      17
        25   |        1      |      2      |      22
        25   |        1      |      3      |      3
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  There are a tremendous number of different possibilities.  Do you really want all of them?

Comment: I'm trying to insert tables now, but having trouble. Should have it updated soon though.

Comment: 30! / (5! * 10! * 15!) = 465817912560 combinations

Comment: The order of the seating within each of the floor doesn't matter, which I think should cut down the possible combinations. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about why one would need all combinations. Seems to me that a pen&paper arrangement would be more efficient. Just generating combo's wouldn't consider extra variables. Like grouping people in the same department together.  Or keeping mortal enemies separated.

Comment: I'm not concerned about those types of variables (departments or personal feelings). Once I have all possible ways to group them (by floor), I have some metrics to compare across to do some optimization. The calculations are easy, but I need the different potential groupings first.

Comment: 465817912560 combinations is without the order of the seating within each of the floor. (Otherwise it should have been 30!.)

Comment: How would I create the query to produce those combinations though?

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer.
Just an example with a lower number of seats.

Even with only 9 seats you get a bunch of scenarios.
With 30 it would be madness!

```
declare @Employees table (id int primary key);
insert into @Employees (id) values 
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Scenarios') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Scenarios;
create table #Scenarios (id int primary key identity(1,1), f1e1 int, f1e2 int, f1e3 int, f1e4 int, f2e1 int, f2e2 int, f2e3 int, f3e1 int, f3e2 int);

INSERT INTO #Scenarios (f1e1, f1e2, f1e3, f1e4, f2e1, f2e2, f2e3, f3e1, f3e2)
SELECT DISTINCT 
 e1.id, e2.id, e3.id, e4.id, e5.id, e6.id, e7.id, e8.id, e9.id
FROM @Employees e1
JOIN @Employees e2 ON e2.id > e1.id
JOIN @Employees e3 ON e3.id > e2.id
JOIN @Employees e4 ON e4.id > e3.id
-- floor 2
JOIN @Employees e5 ON e5.id not in (e1.id, e2.id, e3.id, e4.id)
JOIN @Employees e6 ON e6.id not in (e1.id, e2.id, e3.id, e4.id) and e6.id > e5.id
JOIN @Employees e7 ON e7.id not in (e1.id, e2.id, e3.id, e4.id) and e7.id > e6.id
 -- floor 3
JOIN @Employees e8 ON e8.id not in (e1.id, e2.id, e3.id, e4.id, e5.id, e6.id, e7.id)
JOIN @Employees e9 ON e9.id not in (e1.id, e2.id, e3.id, e4.id, e5.id, e6.id, e7.id) and e9.id > e8.id
ORDER BY e1.id, e2.id, e3.id, e4.id, e5.id, e6.id, e7.id, e8.id, e9.id;

select count(*) as Total
from #Scenarios;

select top 3 *
from #Scenarios
order by id desc;
```

Returns:

```
Total
1260

id      f1e1    f1e2    f1e3    f1e4    f2e1    f2e2    f2e3    f3e1    f3e2
1260    6       7       8       9       3       4       5       1       2
1259    6       7       8       9       2       4       5       1       3
1258    6       7       8       9       2       3       5       1       4
```

The format of the resulting table is different.
But there's still UNPIVOT.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in parts.  The format is different, but creating a table with 500 billion combinations times 30 rows per combination makes no sense.

First, create this table which has different seating positions for 5 people out of 30 for floor 1.  Once this piece is done, you can do this same exercise with 10 people out of 25 remaining by constructing the same type of script with an extra NOT IN @floor_1 clause.

You can use the ID value to cross join to your @floor_2 table if you really want all of the rows.

```
declare @Employees table (id int primary key);
insert into @Employees (id) values 
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30);

declare @floor_1 table (
    id int primary key identity(1,1), 
    emp1 int, 
    emp2 int, 
    emp3 int, 
    emp4 int,
    emp5 INT
    )

INSERT INTO @floor_1
(emp1,emp2,emp3,emp4,emp5)
SELECT a.ID, b.ID, c.ID, d.ID, e.ID
FROM @Employees a
INNER JOIN @Employees b
ON b.ID > a.ID
INNER JOIN @Employees c
ON c.ID > b.ID
INNER JOIN @Employees d
ON d.ID > c.ID
INNER JOIN @Employees e
ON e.ID > d.ID
ORDER BY a.ID, b.ID, c.ID, d.ID, e.ID

SELECT * FROM @floor_1
```